# Show that if $|G| = n$ and 3/4 of G have order 2 then G is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am struggling to show that if $|G| = n$ and 3/4 of elements of G have order 2 then G is abelian.

The only thoughts I have on this so far are that:

(1) At most, 1/4 of elements have order k $\neq 2$.

(2) $\forall g \in G, \exists z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $|G|= n =|g|.z$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is enough to show that $G$ is a $2$ group. Then it will be automoticly abelian.

Comment: I'm unfamliar with what a 2 group is. Could please explain and then show how the truth of $G$ being a $2$ group entails that the group described in my question will be abelian?

Comment: The identity map on $G$ sends more than $3/4$ of the elements of $G$ to their inverses; i.e. all elements of orders $1$ and $2$. Now the result follows from the result proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330138)

Comment: BTW, (1) is incorrect. You mean at most $1/4$ of the elements have order unequal to $2$.