# If $f$ is an automorphism and $|\{a: f(a) = a^{-1}\}| = 3/4 |G|$ then $G$ has an abelian subgroup of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I edited the question to remove the first part as it is already answered here.

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $f$ an automorphism of $G$ and $A = \{a\in G: f(a) = a^{-1}\}$.
>
> Prove that if $|A| = 3/4 |G|$ then $G$ has an abelian subgroup of index $2$.

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330138/if-lbrace-g-in-g-pi-g-g-1-rbrace-frac3g4-then-g-is-an-ab) something (very) related.

Hints or solutions much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, that's the second time today - but this one really is an exact duplicate.

Comment: The question in your title is not the same as the one in the body, could you clarify?

Comment: @DerekHolt why are these duplicates so damn hard to find?! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DerekHolt still, though, I'd like to prove the second part.

Comment: @DerekHolt never mind, it's an easy one.

Comment: I have reopened it, but you should edit the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** If $a,b,ab \in A$ then show that $ab=ba$.

Now, pick some $a \in A$. Use the above hint to show that $|C(a)|>\frac{1}{2}|G|$ (there are less than a quarter bad choices for $b$ and less than a quarter bad choices for $ab$). This shows that $A \subset Z(G)$.

Since $|Z(G)| >1/2 |G|$ the center is $G$.

For the second part, try to show that if $a \in A$ then 
$$C(a) \cap A \geq \frac{1}{2}|G|$$

Show that $C(a) \cap A$ is an Abelian subgroup of $G$. Since $A \neq G$, this subgroup cannot be everything.

Comment: I couldn't show that $C(a) \cap A$ is abelian. Can I get some help with this?

Comment: @Cauchy try to use the fact that if $b, c, bc \in A$ then $bc=cb$.