# Is it necessarly abelian $2$ group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is the following correct ?

Let $n_2$ be a number of elements of $G$ of order $2$ if $n_2> \dfrac {|G|}2$ then $G$ is elemantary abelian $2$ group.

**Edit:** we see that the conclusion "if $n_p> \dfrac {|G|}p$ then $G$ is a $p$ group is wrong" thanks to JyrkiLahtonen.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks, I see.

Comment: Even though it's been answered, you should leave the second question in the OP.

Comment: @MikeMiller: you are right, I guess.

Comment: Oh well. Then I need to retype the comment telling that $D_5$ is a counterexample :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: yeah it can be good :)

Comment: @Jyrki Post it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direct product of an elementary abelian group of order $2^n$ with a dihedral group of order $8$ has $3 \times 2^{n+1} - 1$ involution, so the proportion is $3/4 - 2^{-(n+3)}$.

It is a known result that if at least $3|G|/4$ elements are involutions, then $G$ is elementary abelian. See [Involutions and Abelian Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277127)

Comment: Thanks,
Do you know any other bound for $n_p$ to get $G$ as an $p$ group ?

Comment: I don't know of any bounds for $n_p$. But, for any prime, a Frobenius group with complement $C_p$ will have $n_p/|G| = (p-1)/p$, and you can increase that slightly by taking a direct product with a big elementary abelian $p$-group. So, for $p=3$, by taking $A_4 \times E$, I can get arbitrarily close to $3/4$ for $n_p/|G|$. I don't know if anyone can beat that or prove it's the best possible.